# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" error while installing package in anaconda in windows

Tags: windows, anaconda

I'm getting Error while installing watson package in anaconda by
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud==0.26.1
even though I run the command prompt as administrator mode!(in windows 10, Python 3.6.3)

> Collecting watson-developer-cloud==0.26.1
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out to install as a user:

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud==0.26.1 --user
```

You can also try to use environments.
They are also useful, if you plan to migrate your stuff to the Cloud